# Fitting problem

Tags: fitting

I have two points stored in `data`:

```
data = {{0.0166667, 2.86927*10^-12}, {0.0333333, 1.12725*10^-11}};
```

`data[[All,1]]` contains the time `t`.

`data[[All,2]]` contains the first 2 points of the so called mean squared displacement.

To calculate the particle mass `m` the 2 points should be fitted with the following function:

```
k * T / m * t^2 (* fitting function *)

k = 1.3806488*10^-23;
T = 300;
(* m = particle mass in kg, is the fitting parameter *)
```

Manually I get a good fit if I take `m = 4.1 * 10^-13`kg.

```
dataPlot = 
 ListLinePlot[data, PlotStyle -> {Blue}, 
  Epilog -> {PointSize[Medium], Point[data]}];
manualFitPlot = 
  Plot[k*300/(4.1*10^-13)*t^2, {t, 1/60, 2/60}, PlotStyle -> {Green}];
Show[dataPlot, manualFitPlot, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

**When I try to use `NonlinearModelFit` a wrong result for the mass is obtained**:

```
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, k*300/m*t^2, {m}, t];
nlm["ParameterTable"]
```

$\small \begin{array}{l|llll}
 \text{} & \text{Estimate} & \text{Standard Error} & \text{t-Statistic} & \text{P-Value} \\
\hline
 m & 0.422029 & 4.36728\times 10^{11} & 9.66343 \times 10^{-13} & 1 \\
\end{array}$

I tried different initial values for `m` and also rescaled the small values by multiplying with `(*10^10)`. It did not help.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Are you really attempting to fit two parameters (`m` and the variance about the line) with just two data points?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't be so quick to rule out rescaling your data or working in reduced units, since this works fine:

```
data = {{0.0166667, 2.86927*10^-12}, {0.0333333, 1.12725*10^-11}};
k = 1.3806488*10^-23;
T = 300;
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, k*300/(m*10^-13)*t^2, {m}, t, 
   Method -> "NMinimize"];

(* Gives m = 4.07829 *)
```

I think the problem really lies with the numbers being so small that the default *gradient-based* fitting methods evaluate the gradient as zero in machine precision.

So `NMinimize` works, as does `PrincipalAxis`, since both involve *derivative-free* methods. You can look into it further [in the documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ConstrainedOptimizationLocalNumerical.html).

---

Note that you can also do it without scaling, but specifying a starting value (this time using the `PrincipalAxis` method, which takes two starting values).

```
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, k*300/m*t^2, {{m, 10^-14, 5*10^-13}}, t, 
         EvaluationMonitor :> Print["x = ", m], 
         Method -> "PrincipalAxis"];
(* Gives m = 4.09157*10^-13 *)
(* Also outputs the steps *)
```

Comment: I made a mistake, I rescaled only `data[[All,2]] ` ... thanks a lot

Comment: @mrz you don't need to scale - using a gradient-free method will also work - see my edit, but remember you are using machine-precision numbers.

Comment: So, which fitting value is the better one?

Comment: That's up to you to decide. `NMinimize` probably gives the better results with the Nelder-Mead algorithm than `PrincipalAxis` but I don't know for sure - the crucial point really is derivative-free methods.

Comment: @mrz Probably stick with `NMinimize`.

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick glance, you can try this though. I didn't have time to plot the residuals (or take a look at them for that matter...no pun intended) but it could be worth taking a look at. The function seems to predict your data points with relative accuracy. 
[image: Function]

Answer (score 1):

This model is linear in 1/m, hence use LinearModelFit

```
lm = LinearModelFit[data, {k*300 t^2}, t, IncludeConstantBasis -> False]
```

Then just invert the result:

```
1/lm["BestFitParameters"][[1]]
```

that gives

```
4.07829*10^-13
```

If you give different weights to each point, you will find another result. The "best" result will be obtained with proper weighting.